# mfc CEdit when should I do validation?

Tags: c++, validation, visual-studio-2010, mfc, event-handling

So based on the title, when should I do validation on a CEdit (textbox)?

Background: I was transferred in a new dev group on our company, and their practice is pressing enter, that's when they do their validations on a CEdit (mfc dialog). Whereas I, came from .net, specifically from WinForms, where there are the `Validated` and `Validating` events, which every dev will see and realize that this is the correct event where you should do validation.

My question in detail is:

Should I follow their practice (pressing enter)?
Or what I have in mind is using `EN_KILLFOCUS` (which is close/related to the above events mentioned)? Or both are incorrect and is there an event much more suited for validation?

I need your suggestions since if my co-devs are the ones to be asked, they'll all immediately say that I should handle validation upon pressing enter. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in my company we have two parties.

1st party strictly says information is only validated when Enter is pressed, so in the moment when ALL information is available. Advantage if you have a bunch of information that influences each other this method is easy. The MFC DoDataExchange approach is their favorite.

2nd party says: information must be validated as early as possible. I think this approach is ok when each value is nearly independent. In this case you check all data upon EN_CHANGE or EN_KILLFOCUS and disable the OK button until all data is valid.

Negative to the second method is that you have to give more information to the user in the moment when data is entered, to guide him to correct the data. The first method may explain the problem in one error message.

I use both methods in my programs. And in most cases we use the 1st method, because we found out, that a comprehensive error message with detailed information is easier to maintain and to understand by users, as when they see a dialog an can't get to an enabled OK button...

BTW: I hate dialogs where I can enter negative numbers, where only positive numbers are allowed. Always use the correct and best input fields you can get to allow the best guidance. So the MFC method saying "Out of range" after pressing enter is not a good solution. If you have a minimum and a maximum you can even correct the value directly after the user gave the input.

But this answer and the question tends to be opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you decide to do, you should try to minimize any disruption of the work flow for your users.  And, at the same time, you need to be consistent with what the user has come to expect for validation behavior.  Don’t let your bias impact the dialog behavior in a way that causes the user confusion, or, extra time working with the dialog.  The most important thing to keep in mind is to be consistent with whatever approach you take.

Answer (score -1):

1) MFC provides validation facility for many of the data types. It depends on the type of the data you want to enter in that control. Is this possible use this facility?

In my opinion, EN_KILLFOCUS is a better option because how will validate if the user doesn't press enter and presses tab to move on to the next control? You can still discuss this with your peers and conclude which is a better place to handle the validation.

Comment: [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040419-00/?p=39753).

Comment: I mentioned EN_KILLFOCUS and not WM_KILLFOCUS. EN_KILLFOCUS is sent when an edit control loses the keyboard focus.  Is it not the correct to validate as soon as editing is done?

Comment: It would be correct, if indeed it were sent *"as soon as editing is done"*. The link I posted explains, why the message might get sent too late. Besides, validating input as soon as editing is done is still the wrong approach, as it makes the interface potentially harder to use. Occasionally, a user will enter data, that is *temporarily* invalid (e.g. a date picker, set to February; now the user wishes to enter January, 31st; as soon as they enter `31`, input validation will discard the input, because - well - February doesn't have 31 days).

Comment: The most appropriate way to validate input is to disable the OK/Accept button, as long as the input is invalid, and highlight the input that fails validation. Validation should be non-intrusive, and not ever interfere with the user trying to enter data.

Comment: Agreed, that's why try to validate as soon as user done with entering data. When the user moves on to next control it is a good time to validate data hence do it on EN_KILLFOCUS.